# Linear Algebra - find values of $a$ for which the system has no solutions, infinitely many solutions, or has one solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the values of $a$ for which the system:

> \begin{cases}
> x-2y-3z=4 \\ 
> 3x-y+5z=2        \\
> 4x+y+(a^2 -14)=a+2
> \end{cases}

a) has no solutions
b) has exactly one solution
c) has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Using MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ will make your postings easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm guessing there should be a $z$ after the $(a^2-14)$ in your question... can you please check?

There is exactly one solution if the determinant of the matrix is non-zero:

$\begin{vmatrix} 1 &-2 & -3\\ 3 & -1 & 5\\ 4 & 1 & (a^2-14)\end{vmatrix}\neq 0$

$1(-(a^2-14)-5)-3(-2(a^2-14)+3)+4(-10-3)\neq0$

$-a^2+14-5+6a^2-84-9-52\neq0$

$5a^2-136\neq0$

$5a^2\neq136$

If the determinant is zero, then the number of solutions depends on whether the equations are consistent or not.